Solana Anchor Program - Withdraw Functions says - Error processing Instruction 0: Provided owner is not allowed
I'm coding a tipping program where the tip function transfers the SPL token amount to a PDA address (the PDA of the program itself and the token mint). The tip function works fine, but I'm encountering an error when I try to run the withdraw function. The error message is:
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed:
Error processing Instruction 0: Provided owner is not allowed

Since the program holds the token, it should be the only entity allowed to transfer them to another account. However, the withdrawal is failing. Can anyone help me with this issue?
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

use anchor_spl::token::{transfer, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer};

declare_id!("25vzWQFcgHbthsBhjNEaa6BGrQqCh6YtAFAa4Q0KC4df");

pub const PROGRAM_SEED: &str = "P_SEED";
pub const TIP_SEED: &str = "TIP_SEED";

#[error_code]
pub enum TipError {
    #[msg("The tip has already been claimed.")]
    AlreadyClaimed,
    #[msg("Tip amount can't be 0")]
    InvalidTipAmount,
    #[msg("Invalid withdrawl amount -> can't be 0")]
    InvalidWithdrawAmount,
}

#[program]
mod tip {
    use super::*;

    pub fn give_tip(ctx: Context<GiveTip>, _receiver: Pubkey, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        // Ensure the tip hasn't been claimed already
        if amount <= 0 {
            return Err(TipError::InvalidTipAmount.into());
        }

        let signer = &ctx.accounts.signer;

        let from_ata = &ctx.accounts.from_ata;

        let to_ata = &ctx.accounts.to_ata;

        let token_program = &ctx.accounts.token_program;

        let record_pda = &mut ctx.accounts.record_pda;

        // Transfer tokens from taker to initializer
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: from_ata.to_account_info(),
            to: to_ata.to_account_info(),
            authority: signer.to_account_info().clone(),
        };

        let cpi_program = token_program.to_account_info();

        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

        match transfer(cpi_context, amount) {
            Ok(_) => {
                msg!("Tokens transferred successfully");
            }
            Err(error) => {
                msg!("Failed to transfer tokens: {:?}", error);
                return Err(error.into());
            }
        }

        record_pda.amount += amount;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn withdraw_tip(ctx: Context<WithdrawTip>) -> Result<()> {
        let record_pda = &mut ctx.accounts.record_pda;
        // Ensure the tip hasn't been claimed already
        if record_pda.amount > 0 {
            return Err(TipError::InvalidWithdrawAmount.into());
        }

        let amount = record_pda.amount;

        let from_ata = &ctx.accounts.from_ata;
        let to_ata = &ctx.accounts.to_ata;
        let token_program = &ctx.accounts.token_program;
        let signer = &ctx.accounts.signer;

        let program = &ctx.accounts.program;

        // Transfer tokens from taker to initializer
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: from_ata.to_account_info(),
            to: to_ata.to_account_info(),
            authority: program.to_account_info().clone(),
        };

        let cpi_program = token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

        match transfer(cpi_context, amount) {
            Ok(_) => {
                msg!("Tokens transferred successfully");
            }
            Err(error) => {
                msg!("Failed to transfer tokens: {:?}", error);
                return Err(error.into());
            }
        }

        record_pda.amount = 0;

        Ok(())
    }

}
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(receiver:Pubkey, amount: u64)]
pub struct GiveTip<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub to_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        space = 8 + 8, 
        seeds = [PROGRAM_SEED.as_bytes(), &receiver.key().to_bytes(), TIP_SEED.as_bytes()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub record_pda: Account<'info, Tip>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct WithdrawTip<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [PROGRAM_SEED.as_bytes(), &signer.key().to_bytes(), TIP_SEED.as_bytes()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub record_pda: Account<'info, Tip>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub to_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub program: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Tip {
    pub amount: u64,
}


The culprit is the to_ata account. How are you initializing it?
Your program most likely doesn't have authority over this account and that's my best guess as to why it's failing.
let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: from_ata.to_account_info(),
            to: to_ata.to_account_info(),
            authority: program.to_account_info().clone(), // check here
        };

Also, if your program is the authority, you'll need to declare it as a signer and pass in the keypair on your anchor tests to sign for the transfer.
To avoid this, you could create a PDA owned by the program that has authority over different token accounts and can make transfers for your i.e
// pda to have authority over tokens on your program
#[account]
pub struct AuthorityPDA {
    bump: u8
}

// in the give tip IX

```rust
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(amount: u64)]
pub struct GiveTip<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

     // init it not initialized
    #[account(init_if_needed, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8 + 32, seeds=[b"authorityPda"], bump)]
    pub authority_pda: Account<'info, AuthorityPDA>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = authority,
        associated_token::authority = authority_pda,
        associated_token::mint = mint
    )]
    pub to_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>, 

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

In the withdraw IX you can then use the authority_pda to send the tokens to the receiving address
// signer seeds for authority pda
      let bump = &[ctx.accounts.authority_pda.bump];
      let signer_seeds = &[&[b"authorityPda", bump][..]];

// Transfer tokens from taker to initializer
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: from_ata.to_account_info(),
            to: to_ata.to_account_info(),
            authority: program.to_account_info().clone(),
        };

        let cpi_program = token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);


Could you please provide me with the complete code? I'm finding it quite confusing at the moment because I'm still learning. Once it's clarified, I'll be able to understand how to use this in other programs.

also i want to keep the receiver hiddens, and keeping the tokens in the program ata is important

It's not possible to keep the balances hidden with the original Token program that you are using. For that you might need to check the token extensions hook with the confidential transfer hook that masks transferred amounts between accounts. As for the code, you'll need to add in the missing bits from the code you shared

I don;t want to hide the token balances, I want to create a pda from the mint and program id, and hold it there, and within withdraw i just want to withdraw the tokens to the receiver ( only the amount he receiver yet )
